# Race condition example in Programming Erlang book

Tags: erlang, race-condition

At the end of Chapter 13 of the book *Programming Erlang: Software for a Concurrent World*, we are given a piece of code:

```
keep_alive(Name, Fun) ->
    register(Name, Pid = spawn(Fun)),
    on_exit(Pid, fun(_Why) -> keep_alive(Name, Fun) end).
```

And the book says:

- The process `Pid` may die before `on_exit` is executed.
- The code has a race condition that could happen **if two programs try to evaluate `keep_alive` at the same time and with the same value of `Name`**.

If two programs call `keep_alive` with the same `Name` at the same time, then one of the `register` calls will trigger a `badarg` exception since the name has been taken, and calling process will die.

So, it's not *process `Pid` dies before `on_exit` is called*, but *the process calling `on_exit` dies*

What's the author's point here by using this as an example to describe the race condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *either* may actually die.

The process referred to by `Pid` might have a bug in the first line of `Fun`, it may try to acquire some external resource as its first action and 
fail (a locked file, a nonexistant database, whatever), it may terminate *very* quickly without looping, etc.

```
-module(silly).
-export([do_stuff/0]).

do_stuff() ->
   keep_alive(die_bot, fun i_die_fast/0).

i_die_fast() ->
    not_ok = io:format("Is this ok?~n"),
    receive Anything ->
        ok = io:format("Received: ~tp~n", [Anything]),
        i_die_fast()
    end.

keep_alive(Name, Fun) ->
    register(Name, Pid = spawn(Fun)),
    on_exit(Pid, fun(_Why) -> keep_alive(Name, Fun) end).
```

How would the code above play out? (`io:format/1` always returns `ok`, so it will not match `not_ok` and crash in the first line.) `i_die_fast/0` appears to recurse forever, but it never gets that far, and will probably die before `on_exit/2` is reached. (But it is not *guaranteed* to die before `on_exit/2` is called! Welcome to concurrency.)

The point is you don't really know. The closest you can come to knowing is using `spawn_link` or, in a less coupled circumstance `spawn` then `monitor` or `spawn_monitor`.

The race condition with `register` is true as well and could crash the currently executing process -- so that's *two* race conditions.

---

Side note:

This is why I nearly always have the spawned function register itself so that if there is a conflict, it blows up in the context of the child, not the caller (in most cases, there are all sorts of reasons why you might want to do it the other way):

```
% Note, we don't need the PID of `some_helper` because it is named.
start() ->
    _ = spawn_link(fun() -> some_helper() end),
    main_loop().

some_helper() ->
    true = register(helper, self()),
    helper_loop().
```